# How do I force layout before segue animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a view controller that shows content on the full screen, including behind the status bar and navigation bar. Those bars may be toggled hidden/not hidden, and as such, the controller constantly overrides self.view.frame to maintain the content covering the full screen (i.e. preventing auto-layout from shifting the content down slightly when the bars reappear, shifting it up when they disappear). The content is a scroll view, and nested inside is an image view that may be zoomed by the scroll view. This controller is pushed by a parent controller all the time, and it has the vertical cover animation.

However, I'm running into a problem that when it is first presented, the scroll view's frame is not set properly, and as such, the image is initially off-center, and will appear to "jump" to its correctly centered position after the animation completes, and the main thread resumes layout functions instead of animation. After that initial issue, everything works as expected.

If I disable animation entirely, it works as expected. I believe it has to do with the view controller's lifecycle. During viewDidLoad, the scroll view has an incorrect frame size (the nib default), and it is not corrected by auto-layout until layoutSubviews is called. However, I need the frame to be set far before that, since the presenting animation is already working during that time. I also cannot disable auto-layout unless it's doable just for this specific view controller.

Comment: Hi. I'm running up against the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This problem really bugged me, I tried every variant of viewDid* method and was about to try out a custom segue when I decided to try this...

On the presenting view controller...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [vc.view setNeedsLayout];
    [vc.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Note, just calling [vc.view layoutSubviews] won't do anything as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews), you need to use setNeedsLayout and then call layoutIfNeeded.

In the destination view controller, use `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` to do your updates.